# How to set the Priority for feature file inside include tag

Tags: selenium, testng-eclipse

How to set the priority for feature file(s) to run in the TestNG.xml file with include tag.

I have added the "priority" attribute inside the include tag as follows:

```
<test name="DESKTOP Chrome" enabled="true">
<parameter name="platform" value="desktop" />
<parameter name="driver.name" value="chromeDriver" />
<parameter name="webdriver.chrome.driver" value="driver/chromedriver.exe" />
<parameter name="chrome.additional.capabilities" value="{'chromeOptions':{'useAutomationExtension':false}}"/>
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="@aLoginMenuDesktop" priority="1"/>
            <include name="@ViewPrimaryNavigationMenuDesktop" priority="2"/>
            <include name="@PortfolioOverview" priority="3"/>
            <include name="@FooterDesktop" priority="4"/>
            <include name="@zSignOutMenuDesktop" priority="5"/> 
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>
        <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

But during the execution it throws the below error.

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17;
>   columnNumber: 54; Attribute "priority" must be declared for element
>   type "include".   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the priority inside the tag and make it run by default instead,
I just found out that the priority by default (alphabetical) is not based on the tag name of the feature file (@faturefile) that is being called

But, it is based from the filename of the feature file (teststep.feature)